# How to use reduce to solve this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I have this simple equation to solve (1 == 62.5*E^(-30*10^6/x), {x}), and Mathematica is able to give a correct answer. However, there is this warning message ([image: warning message]) I don't understand, can anyone elaborate what this message means?

Answer (score 1):

There are many complex-valued solutions; Mathematica gives you the unique real-valued one here but warns you about the loss of generality. If you want all solutions, try

```
Reduce[1 == 125/2*E^(-30*10^6/x), x]
```

Comment: Or `Solve[1 == 125/2*E^(-30*10^6/x), x, Method -> Reduce]`

Comment: Thanks! Both methods work well.

Answer (score 0):

Tell Mathematica that you search for  a real solution:

```
Solve[1 == 125/2*E^(-30*10^6/x), x, Reals]
(*{{x -> -(30000000/(Log[2] - 3 Log[5]))}}*)
```

Comment: Thanks, I do only need reals, great suggestion.